# Включить механизм шифрования в jvm

Tags: java

Как включить механизм шифрования памяти в jvm? Для предотвращения Dll инъекций и замены переменных используя CheatEngine (как в denuvo)

Comment: Такой вообще есть? Почему бы вам не шифровать сами значения переменных?

Comment: @AntonSorokin, приложение уже написано. а переписывать или добавлять костыли не очень хочется

Comment: если ответ помог вам или решил вашу проблему(или доказал, что решения нет), то плюсаните его или примите, нажав на стрелку и галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, включить шифрование памяти в jvm нельзя.

Если вы храните данные в `String`:

Вы можете использовать `GuardedString` для обеспечения безопасности паролей. Это специальный объект `String`, созданный для решения вопросов, связанных с хранением паролей в памяти, представленных `String`:

Пакет [org.identityconnectors.common.security.GuardedString](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.syncope.identityconnectors/framework/0.2.3/org/identityconnectors/common/security/GuardedString.java). Документация:

> Secure string implementation that solves the problems associated with
>   keeping passwords as java.lang.String. That is, anything represented
>   as a String is kept in memory as a clear text password and stays in
>   memory at least until it is garbage collected. The GuardedString class
>   alleviates this problem by storing the characters in memory in an
>   encrypted form. The encryption key will be a randomly-generated key.
>   In their serialized form, GuardedString will be encrypted using a
>   known default key. This is to provide a minimum level of protection
>   regardless of the transport. For communications with the Remote
>   Connector Framework it is recommended that deployments enable SSL for
>   true encryption. Applications may also wish to persist GuardedStrings.
>   In the case of Identity Manager, it should convert GuardedStrings to
>   EncryptedData so that they can be stored and managed using the Manage
>   Encryption features of Identity Manager. Other applications may wish
>   to serialize APIConfiguration as a whole. These applications are
>   responsible for encrypting the APIConfiguration blob for an additional
>   layer of security (beyond the basic default key encryption provided by
>   GuardedString).

Если у злоумышленника есть root-доступ к компьютеру, он может прочитать всю память, выполнить операции отладки, выполнить обратный инжиниринг вашего байт-кода java и т.д., то есть нет никакого практического способа помешать злоумышленнику получить данные, которые где-то спрятаны в оперативной памяти. Также вы можете зашифровать swap file/partition.

Вы можете шифровать сами данные лежащие в переменных. Также чтобы усложнить предполагаемым взломщикам понимание вашего кода(т.е. что как работает), вы можете [обфусцировать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) код.